# What happens when a electrically charged object is moving away from a charge it is attracted to(read description)

Tags: electromagnetism, inertia

When a electrically charged object that carries momentum and inertia is attracted to a electrical field and is moving away from it, does it lose momentum as it is pulled towards it, or does it circle around retaining it's momentum? or some combination of the two? is there some sort of mathematical formula to describe this? What if the object is moving away perpendicular to the charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth noting that (classically) the electromagnetic force has an equivalent functional form to the gravitational force. If you have two oppositely charged particles the force between them is
$$\vec{F} = -\frac{k \left|q_1\right| \left|q_2\right|}{r^2}\hat{r}$$
where $k = 1/4\pi \epsilon_0$. Compare to the gravitational force
$$\vec{F} = -\frac{G m_1 m_2}{r^2}\hat{r}$$
From a classical perspective (ignoring magnetic fields due to moving charges), you can simply think of how massive bodies interact gravitationally. There would be elliptic bound orbits (think planets) and hyperbolic scattering trajectories. If we consider the effects of magnetic fields however, the acceleration of the charges will cause the emission of radiation, which will carry away momentum and energy, causing orbits to decay. This is of course fixed by quantum mechanics and quantum field theory, where there are stable bound states, but then we can no longer talk about trajectories.